# Adding rows after specific timestamp

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

Short story: - While doing my analysis, I forgot to account for inter-day and inter-week values. I need to add them to my table.

Long story:
I have this table:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df<-structure(list(time = structure(c(1488987000, 1488988800, 1488990600, 
                                      1488992400, 1488994200, 1488996000, 1488997800, 1488999600, 1489001400, 
                                      1489003200, 1489005000, 1489006800, 1489069800, 1489071600, 1489073400, 
                                      1489075200, 1489077000, 1489078800, 1489080600, 1489082400, 1489084200, 
                                      1489086000, 1489087800, 1489089600, 1489091400, 1489093200, 1489156200, 
                                      1489158000, 1489159800, 1489161600, 1489163400, 1489165200, 1489167000, 
                                      1489168800, 1489170600, 1489172400, 1489174200, 1489176000, 1489177800, 
                                      1489179600, 1489411800, 1489413600, 1489415400, 1489417200, 1489419000
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = structure("America/New_York", .Names = "TZ")), 
low.yields = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("time", 
                                                                "low.yields"), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                  "data.frame"))
```

There are two columns, timestamps, and dummy variable.

I would like to add and replicate all rows which have visible hour in timestamp 16:00 and change the timestamp to 9:00, but in the same day as is the next row. Notice that this does not have to be the next day, but it could be over the weekend as well.

Up till now I found function `tibble::add_row`, however I am not sure how to replicate the specific rows. However, if I do

```
df %>% add_row(.after = which(hour(df$time) == 16))
```

I get at least empty row only for the first value, not all.

At this moment, table looks like this:

```
   time                 low.yields
   ...                  ...
26 2017-03-09 16:00:00  1
27 2017-03-10 09:30:00  0
   ...                  ...
```

afterwards, I would like to make it look like this. Time is half an hour smaller than row below, and low.yields value is inherited from row above. This will be done for every row where there is time 16:00.

```
   time                 low.yields
   ...                  ...
26 2017-03-09 16:00:00  1
27 2017-03-10 09:00:00  1
28 2017-03-10 09:30:00  0
   ...                  ...
```

Comment: Please add the expected output.

Comment: You have specified only the `.after`, but what about the values?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I added further explanation. At this moment I did not care about the values as I was not able to identify the correct rows. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: + I added also longer example, this one also have weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after big help from @akrun, I came up to solution to my problem.

```
df %>%
    filter(hour(time)==16) %>%
    mutate(time = as.POSIXct(paste(as.Date(time), "09:00:00"), tz = "America/New_York") ) %>% 
    mutate(time = time + days(ifelse(wday(time) == 6, 3, 1))) %>%
    bind_rows(df, .) %>% 
    arrange(time)
```

Thanks a lot for your help.